# CAML or C#: Change the URL of "Edit Item"  of Custom List item

Tags: caml-query, editing-menu, custom

How can I change the target URL of "Edit Item" option of a custom list in CAML or .net?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It might help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, i created an app page, i want when user clicks edit in EBC, to go to this app page instead of the default edit form.

Comment: That seems a strange way to do things. You could just edit the Edit form for your list or list definition.

Comment: I am creating a WP to work out of the box, so no Sharepoint designer, only VS2010

Answer (score 1):

Using SharePoint Designer you can [change the page associated to editing list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-HA010119111.aspx#BM3) items.

Comment: Thanks, but how to do in VS?